# Does channel capacity depend on the valence of the signal to be transmitted?

Tags: telecommunication

Say I have a channel with bandwidth W and I want to send data at a rate Rb. Do my SNR requirements vary if I use binary, quaternary, 8-ary or 16-ary signalling scheme?

For example let's say I have a 1000 Hz bandwidth and  I want to send data at 100 bits/s, and I calculate that I would need an SNR of 0.072 (-11dB). Now if I plan on using quaternary signalling (2B1Q), I would only need to send 50 symbols per second. Can I therefore inject the 50 into Shannon's channel capacity formula and calculate an even lower required SNR?

My understanding is that in Shannon's formula, C is expressed in bits/s, not symbols/s, so I'm thinking it's not possible to do that. Is it so?

Comment: What is the definition of SNR (for r-ary system) ? Will the same amount of noise correspond to a lower SNR since the **r** symbols are crammed together in the same *range* ? Then you might not gain anything.

Comment: It's the power of the signal, regardless of valence, divided by the power of the noise. For your second question, that's what I'm trying to figure out.